# How to have a horizontal scroll bar when a column in the output is really long when using Jupyter and Python

Tags: python, output, scrollbar, jupyter

I am trying to use Jupyter + Python. Here is an example of the output

[image]

You can see the because the column 'correspondencedata' is too long, so it can not be shown fully in the output.

Can I change this so that a horizontal scroll bar will occur when a column has too long content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', nbr_pixel)` before.

If you use a number big enough it will always show the entire content of your cells.

Like, `pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 4000)`

For more informations:

```py
## To see the actual settings : 
pd.get_option("display.max_colwidth")

## To reset with default value
pd.reset_option("max_colwidth")
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)